# VB.Net Display data in datagridview with headers set manually

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have transaction data that will be displayed in datagridview, but I am having difficulty with the header that I created manually in datagridview
This is a transaction that I created and saved into the database
[image]

in search, I recall this transaction to display

```
Private Sub fillform()

    Dim table As New DataTable

    dtproductdetail.DataSource = Nothing

    Try
        cmddetail = New SqlCommand("SELECT AP_T_PR_D.ProdCode, IV_M_Product.ProdName, AP_T_PR_D.QTY, IV_M_PackingType.PackingName
                        FROM IV_M_PackingType RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                        IV_M_Product ON IV_M_PackingType.PackingCode = IV_M_Product.PackingCodeDown RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                        AP_T_PR_D ON IV_M_Product.ProdCode = AP_T_PR_D.ProdCode
                        WHERE AP_T_PR_D.PRNumber = '" & selectedrow.Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "' ", conn)

        Adp = New SqlDataAdapter(cmddetail)
        Adp.Fill(table)
        dtproductdetail.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        dtproductdetail.DataSource = table
        dtproductdetail.Refresh()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "fillform", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try
End Sub
```

result

[image]

Comment: Noooo! Don't use string concatenation to put the selected cell value into the query!

Answer (score 0):

This code is called when the form loads and styles the DataGridView dgvTX

```
    Private Sub StyleDGV()

    'Set Design of the DataGridView
    dgvTX.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Times New Roman", 13.0F, FontStyle.Bold)
    dgvTX.ColumnCount = 8
    dgvTX.Columns(0).Width = 50   'ID
    dgvTX.Columns(1).Width = 140  'Date
    dgvTX.Columns(2).Width = 136  'TxType
    dgvTX.Columns(3).Width = 120  'Amt
    dgvTX.Columns(4).Width = 114  'ckNum
    dgvTX.Columns(5).Width = 390  'Desc
    dgvTX.Columns(6).Width = 130  'Bal
    dgvTX.Columns(7).Width = 10  'dumbS
    'To Set Col Header Size Mode = Enabled
    'To Set Col Header Default Cell Styles DO in Properties
    dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"


    dgvTX.ColumnHeadersHeight = 10 'Sans Serif 'Tahoma
    dgvTX.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Sans Serif", 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold)

    dgvTX.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
    dgvTX.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
    dgvTX.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    dgvTX.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight


    'dgvTX.Enabled = False 'Prevents Selection of data and scrolling
    'DGV Header Names
    dgvTX.Columns(0).Name = "TID"
    dgvTX.Columns(1).Name = "  Date"
    dgvTX.Columns(2).Name = "  Tx Type"
    dgvTX.Columns(3).Name = "  Amount"
    dgvTX.Columns(4).Name = "  CK Num"
    dgvTX.Columns(5).Name = "Desctiption"
    dgvTX.Columns(6).Name = "  Balance"
    dgvTX.Columns(7).Name = "     "


    dgvTX.Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(1).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(2).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(3).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(4).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(5).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(6).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable

End Sub
```

Comment: But why write that code at all when all those properties can be set in the designer?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Because I have better control over the design and setting in the properties is labor intensive PLUS I can recycle this code in other projects by just altering a few variables Try it you will like it

Comment: *"I have better control over the design"*. No you don't. None of what you did there can;t be done in the designer. They are the same properties so you have the same level of control. *"setting in the properties is labor intensive"*. Is clicking a few boxes really more labour-intensive than typing that code? I would say not. *"I can recycle this code in other projects"*. What you do in the designer generates code so you can copy that code to another project just as easily as you can copy your manually-written code. *"you will like it"*. I assure you that I will not.

Comment: I have successfully tried with column add datapropertyname and set datagrid with code, but the problem arises when i try to edit to add a new product row. 'Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.'

Answer (score -1):

If you created the columns in the designer, which I assume is what you mean, then why have you set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `True`? If you are creating columns manually then you don't want to create them automatically.

Set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` and make sure that the `DataPropertyName` is set correctly for each grid column. It should be set to the `ColumnName` of the `DataColumn` you want it to bind to.

In actual fact, if you do that and there are the same number of grid and table columns, it won't matter what `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to. Your issue is specifically that you have not set the `DataPropertyName` properly or maybe at all for at least some of those grid columns.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change AutoGenerateColumns to false, but I tried your suggestion by adding "dtproductdetail.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Product Code", .DataPropertyName = "ProductCode"})" according to propertyname column, but only column 3 is filled, my notes are columns 0,1,2, and 4 readonly true

Comment: @BambangSetiawan, why are you adding code at all? Why aren't you adding these columns in the designer?